# Mean Curvature Inequality

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $H$ be the mean curvature of a surface $S$ which is graph over a disc centered at the origin with radius $r$. If $H\geq a$ at all points, prove that $ar\leq 1$.

I believe  I have proven it, but it is rather cumbersome, so I am looking for a nicer shorter proof.

**Proof Using Tangent Spheres:**  Let $X:(u,v)\in D_r\rightarrow (u,v,h(u,v))$ be the parametrization of $S$. $C=X(\bar{D}_R)$, where $R<r$, is a compact set because $X$ is a homeomorphism. Let us consider the point $p_x=(0,0,x)$. Define $G(x,s)=|p_x-s|$ defined in $[-L-r,L+r] \times C$, such that $[-L,L]$ is large enough to contain the largest and smallest height in $C$. Taking $s=(0,0,h(0,0))$ there is $p_x=(0,0,h(0,0)+R)$ for which $G(x,s)=R$. Thus $G^{-1}(R)=\{(x,s)| G(x,s)=R\}$ is a nonempty compact set (it is clearly closed and the domain of $G$ is bounded).

Let $(a_1,s_1)$ be one point with lowest first coordinate in $G^{-1}(R)$. Likewise, $(a_2,s_2)$ one point with largest first coordinate. The spheres with radius $R$ centered in $a_i$ must have no points of $S$ in its interior, because if they did, one would be able to decrease $a_1$, or increase $a_2$.

Furthermore each sphere centered in $a_i$ must be tangent to $S$. If it weren't, there would be a curve in $S$ passing through $(a_i,s_i)$ whose derivative has a component in the same direction as the normal vector of the sphere. Thus, there would be points of $S$ interior to the sphere (more explicitly $\langle \alpha-p,\alpha-p\rangle$ would have a nonzero derivative and the distance to the center would decrease), which couldn't be the case.

Suppouse the Gauss Normal application of $S$ points upwards. In this case, we have that the sphere is locally above in $s_2$. This means that $k_j=\mathrm{I\!I}_s^S(e_j,e_j)\leq \mathrm{I\!I}_s^{B_{s_2}^R}(e_1,e_1)=\frac{1}{R}$. This yields:

$$H(s_2)=\frac{k_1+k_2}{2}\leq \frac{1}{R}\Rightarrow H(s_2) R \leq 1\Rightarrow \lim_{R\rightarrow r^-}H(s_2)R\leq 1\Rightarrow H(s_2) r \leq 1$$